# How to properly retarget STM32 fprintf to multiple destinations (uarts)?

Tags: gcc, stm32

I am trying to use fprintf (or printf) to multiple destinations (UARTS) using GCC

Overriding _write_r works only for stderr:

```
int _write_r(void *reent, int fd, char *ptr, size_t len) // stderr
{
    __asm volatile ("nop");
    __asm volatile ("nop");

    return _write((FILE*)fd, ptr, len);

    //return 0;
}

fprintf (stdout, "Error reading file" ) ; // works!
```

But trying this is not working, _write_r() is not called at all.

```
fprintf ((FILE *)USART1, "Error reading file 2" ) ;
```

So basically I plan to use a switch/case depending on destinations.

Some examples are available on ST community, but are using __io_putchar(int ch) which leaves no possibility to switch between destinations.

Any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: When I've done similar things before, I made my own version of `_write()`, which overrides the weak version provided by CubeIDE. I'm not sure what you mean by "only works for stderr".

Comment: Or just make your own output function. You can use `sprintf()` or similar to get all the formatting stuff that you want.

Comment: `_write((FILE*)fd, ptr, len);` I do not think you understand what cast does. `(FILE *)fd` is gibberish.

Answer (score 1):

Use `fopencookie` to open your own stream with custom callbacks. You could create your like `fopenusart` built on top like the following:

```
   #define _GNU_SOURCE
   #include <stdio.h>
   static ssize_t usart_read(void *cookie, char *buf, size_t size) {
      UART_HandleTypeDef *usart = cookie;
      HAL_StatusTypeDef s = HAL_UART_Transmit(usart, buf, size);
      return s == HAL_OK ? size : -1;
   }
   // etc.
   static const cookie_io_functions_t usart_functions = {
       .read = usart_read,
       // etc.
   };
   FILE *fopenusart(UART_HandleTypeDef *usart, const char *mode) {
       return fopencookie(usart, mode, usart_functions);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to reply my own question, but all that I found is a way too complicated for a STM32 Cortex M0 platform. Standard NANO library still occupies 4K, no mention redirect implementation.

I simply wanted a common printf() function able to redirect to USARTs, RAM, LCD or ALL other devices at runtime.

The easiest way to do it was to take a simple (tiny) printf implementation, at first google search I found this one
https://github.com/heartoftechnology/embedded-printf

Modify the prototype to this

```
void embedded_printf(void *stream, const char *format, ...)
```

Modify the putchar() to this (to accept stream also)

```
void embedded_putChar(void *stream, uint8_t c)
```

Design the putchar() like this

```
void embedded_putChar(void *stream, uint8_t c) {

    switch ((uint32_t)(stream))
    {
        default:
    
            break;
    
        case (uint32_t)USART2:
    
                // putc() for USART2
            break;

    }
}
```

And that's all.

Comment: `Standard NANO library still occupies 4K,` Use `setvbuf` on standard streams to reduce the size of FILE buffers. I [typically had](https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/kamillibc/-/blob/master/libs/uni/stm32/uni.c#L22) that in some `__attribute__(__init__)` section. I agree the default newlib buffers are very big for M0, but so are FILE* streams.

Comment: too complicated :) I spent 1 day to make'it work properly and it doesn't. I just use a 3'rd party modified printf() and that's it. thanks!

Comment: `void embedded_printf(void *stream, const char *format, ...)` -> `int  embedded_printf(void *stream, const char *format, ...)`